# For local co-op, does everyone have to own the game?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

The PS3 version of Diablo 3 came out, and it has local multiplayer for up to 4 players on one screen. So I guess you have to purchase at least one copy of the game, but what about the other 3 players?

Comment: I *severely* doubt all players have to own the game, but note you probably have to have accounts for all other players on the console (in most games it will otherwise use a "guest" account and not save the co-op partners data without a profile). No answer though because I don't have the game in question so I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one copy is enough to play with all 4 players on the same console. You will need several controllers though :p